# git clone Permissions 644 on master, 777 on clone

Tags: git

- Running dual-boot (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/Windows 10)
- Booted into Ubuntu
- When running "git clone" in Ubuntu partition location, cloned file permissions are correct (i.e. 644 for files and 755 for directories)
- When running "git clone" in Windows partition location, cloned files and directories permissions are all incorrect: 777

example:

Ubuntu partition:

```
cd /home/myuser/clonehere/
git clone https://github.com/myrepo/myrepo.git
result: /home/myuser/clonehere/
  files=644, directories=755 CORRECT
```

Windows partition:

```
cd /media/myuser/Windows/Users/Public/Documents/clonehere/
git clone https://github.com/myrepo/myrepo.git
result: /media/myuser/Windows/Users/Public/Documents/clonehere/
  files=777, directories=777 INCORRECT
```

Ubuntu partition result:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 stupidscript stupidscript  4096 Sep 18 14:31 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 stupidscript stupidscript    68 Sep 18 14:31 .gitignore
```

Windows partition result:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 stupidscript stupidscript   4096 Sep 18 14:36 .git
-rwxrwxrwx 1 stupidscript stupidscript     68 Sep 18 14:36 .gitignore
```

Tried setting umask 0022 before clone and adding /etc/wsl.conf, no change.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Git doesn't do anything at all here. The real question is why this Windows mount point isn't obeying umask settings. I suspect the answer is that Windows mount points just don't do any permissions at all, but that's a question about Windows mount points (in your OS), not about Git.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/12/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

Comment: Thank you, torek.
This is the path I will follow.